# FFmpeg HLS single file playback is broken when encryption enabled

Tags: ffmpeg, encryption, video-conversion, video-streaming, hls

HLS files generated with encryption enabled and the single segment (byte range) option result in videos that are unplayable. The same videos play without issue when encryption is not utilized.

Here is command.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 6 -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_flags single_file -hls_enc 1 -hls_key_info_file ainfo.key  1.m3u8
```

This is basically same error as reported here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5858

Anyone know if it works in newer versions? At least not working for me.